# Highcharts - showing newly added points after selecting rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

On sample provided by Highcharts https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-datagrouping-last-anchor after clicking on rangeSelector button (YTD) the XAxis freezes and does not extend and does not move to show newly added points (despite having: *lastAnchor: 'lastPoint'*)

```
    dataGrouping: {
        approximation: 'average',
        enabled: true,
        forced: true,
        units: [
            ['millisecond', [5]]
        ],
        lastAnchor: 'lastPoint'
    }
```

[image]

After clicking on All it works again.

How to make the chart to show newly added points while rangeSelector is on?

Comment: It seems to be an issue related to the `rangeSelector.button` clicking and `setInterval()` in the `chart.load()` event. I investigate this issue and will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, after double-checking I reported a bug that you can track here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18239 Thank you for pointing out this behavior!

Comment: Thanks. I hope it will be fixed soon.